# How to maintain stock while huge traffic in ecommerce portal

Tags: php, error-handling, e-commerce, cart, payment-processing

Currently I am working on a ecommerce application, due to huge traffic I was unable to handle product availability. e.g. when to user buying product1 having stoke quantity 1 and both are in checkout page then they process for payment process. At that time my order placed for both the user and one of them has blank order details. I can not provide code for the reference. Please check the flow screenshot.

Purchase Process

[image]

Comment: Without seeing what you tried no one can specifically point out what you did wrong or how to improve your service. If you can't show the code at least try writing your idea in pseudo-code and mask out some of the details. However, I would suggest you use some type of `Queue` and a certain delay time to get out of this problem (Given you haven't used any queue).

Comment: I have provided the flow process on behalf of code or pseudo-code. Which I think demonstrate the problem. As this is a ecommerce application there is thousand lines of code, how would I know which one is wrong formatted query. If you have work on such project or any issue like this, you can ask @omarjayed